# Route python actions to a shell sub process

Tags: python

I am making a weird little python program where I am using mplayer to read a video stream in on stdin via an os call:

`os.system('gphoto2 --capture-movie --stdout | mplayer - -nosound -vf screenshot')`

As the command implies, I'd like to be able to take a screenshot by pressing the 's' key. And actually, I'd like that to be hooked to a RPi gpio command.

But my over arching question is, after launching this command in python, how can I route keystrokes to that subprocess?

Comment: [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) is a fairly primitive call that doesn't provide much (any?) control. Look at using the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module, there's even a section with [examples of piping commands and replacing `os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements).